# How to get Dynamic form values in react 17.0.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am form which is generated dynamically.

```
{
    schedule[0] ?
    Object.keys(schedule[0]).map((j, i) => (
        <Col sm={12} xs={12} md={3} lg={3}>
            <Form.Group controlId={j}>
                <Form.Label>{j}</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    required
                    onChange={(event) => { setVendorName(event.target.value) }}
                />
            </Form.Group>
         </Col>
     ))
     :
     <p style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}>Loading</p>
 }
```

My State :

```
const [vendorName, setVendorName] = useState('');
```

inside onsubmit function :

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('vendorName', vendorName);
```

This generated **four input type text html**, How to save the values of the input tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an object into `useState`. In the `onChange` function, you can put the `setFormValue` in it. `[event.target.name]` is the dynamic key of the input so that the `formValue` will update accordingly.

```
const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({input1: "",input2: "",input3: "",input4: "",});

Object.keys(schedule[0]).map((j, i) => (
        <Col sm={12} xs={12} md={3} lg={3}>
            <Form.Group controlId={j}>
                <Form.Label>{j}</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    name={`input${i+1}`}
                    required
                    onChange={(event) => { setFormValue([event.target.name]:{event.target.value}) }}/>
            </Form.Group>
         </Col>
     ))

/>
```

Comment: just for example i have mentioned 4 input tags, there are n number of input tags which are unknown.

Comment: The above code should work find with n numbers of input tags. The key point is you need to set the related key you want to use in the ```useState``` first. and the ```name``` in the input tag.

Comment: {Sno: Array(1), input1: Array(1), input2: Array(1), input2: Array(1), input3: Array(1), …}

How return this into an single array ?

Comment: Why need to turn it into a single array? You mean objects of array?